# How to add product with custom option type file to cart programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, addtocart

I am creating a functionality to add product to cart programmatically with **Custom Option type File**.

I am using the below code to add product :

```
$cart = Mage::helper ( 'checkout/cart' )->getCart ();
$product = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product' )->load(949);
$params['product'] = 949;
$options['options_32_file_action'] = 'save_new';
$params['options_32_file_action'] = 'save_new';
$params['options'] = $options;
$params['qty'] = 1;
$cart->addProduct ( $product, $params);
```

**Uploaded file :**

```
$_FILES['options_25_file'] = array
            (
                "name" => "1.png",
                "type" => "application/octet-stream",
                "tmp_name" => Mage::getBaseDir()."/1.png",
            );
```

I am getting this below error :

> The product has required options

I tried most of the solution provided on this site but can't fix this.

Kindly let me know is this the right approach or if there any other way to do this please refer me.